# Visual Studio Online alternate credentials not available

Tags: azure-devops

I am trying to hook up Atlassian Source Tree to my GIT repository on Visual Studio Online.  To do so, you have to enable alternate credentials.  However, when I go to the screen for alternate credentials it has a warning message that says "Alternate Credentials have been disabled for your account."

I can click the "enable alternate credentials" and put in a password but the error message is still there at the top of the form and Source Tree doesn't work.

How do I enable credentials?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a setting that controls it for the account. Are you the account owner?

If so, from your account home page, click the gear icon in the upper right. Then click on the Settings tab. Check under Application Connections and enable alternate authentication credentials.

[image]